# Program to fine-tune pre-trained word embeddings on my data set

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, software-recommendation

I am looking for a program that would allow me to fine-tune pre-trained word embeddings on my data set. Ideally, open source and working on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Also, see the _"Embedding Fine-Tuning"_ section on the page 5 of [this paper](http://lebret.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/nips2013.pdf) - I know, it's not software, but I thought it might give you some useful ideas.

Answer (score 4):

While I am not aware of software *specifically* for **tuning** trained word embeddings, perhaps the following *open source software* might be helpful, if you can figure out what parts can be modified for the fine-tuning part (just an idea off the top of my head - I'm not too familiar with the details):

- [GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove) (part of *Stanford NLP Group* software);
- [SENNA](http://ml.nec-labs.com/senna) (its use for word embeddings is mentioned in [this blog post](http://lebret.ch/words));
- [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/vaswani/WORD_OBSERVATION_RBM_NCE) for Deep Learning-based word embeddings training;
- [Neural Probabilistic Language Model Toolkit](http://nlg.isi.edu/software/nplm), mentioned above (also Deep Learning-based).

Answer (score 2):

If you use SGNS or CBOW, https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/ will let you continue continue training a pre-trained model on a different corpus if that is what you mean by fine tuning.